# Should there be a separate tag for each plugin?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have a separate tag for each plugin, instead of a generic [plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) tag to cover them all?

If so, what should be the naming convention for such tags?

Answer (score 20):

I think that a generic [plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) tag is too broad for questions about a specific plugin.

I suggest [plugin-fugitive](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-fugitive), [plugin-nerdtree](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-nerdtree), etc.  Putting "plugin-" as a prefix rather than as a suffix lets them be grouped together in an alphabetical listing.

Comment: That prefixing idea is a great idea.

Comment: Should there be agreement on the standard formatting for the name used after the "plugin-" part?

Comment: @kenny What standard do you have in mind?

Comment: I would suggest the string that the author of the plugin has as its default installation directory for pathogen-style installs. Ex: plugin-vim-json, plugin-fugitive, plugin-html5.vim ? (Can you do '.' in a tag?)

Comment: @kenny Sounds reasonable. The `.` character is allowed in tags.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more likely that is to help avoid tag name collisions.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, create a tag for the plugin if you're asking a question about it. 200_success' suggestion to prefix them with `plugin-` is a good idea.

[plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) should be for questions about Vim's plugin system, in general. For eample: "*In which directories does Vim search for plugins?*".

Comment: My first thought on reading this answer was what a great idea, but I thought about it for a bit, and I know that the plugin tag is going to be abused, so how about vim-plugin as a tag and blacklist plugin?

Comment: @hildred Yeah, that sounds like a good idea. neovim plugins are also different, so we would then have `vim-plugin` and `neovim-plugin` (...and perhaps more?) ... Maybe even `vim-plugin-system` or some such?