# The plugins tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[plugins](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) currently has this excerpt:

> Vim's plugin system. DO NOT use this for questions that may require a plugin. For plugin-specific questions, use the appropriate plugin-* tag for those.

However, most people use this tag for questions that are either about a specific plugin (*"How do I get foo to work with plugin bar?"*) or for questions where they assume the answer involves a plugin (*"How do I do foo?"*).

I would propose:

1. Rename [plugins](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) to [plugin-development](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development) or [plugin-system](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-system); this should make the intent clearer. Some example questions for this tag:

   - [How to design a command in a plugin that can be called from vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/how-to-design-a-command-in-a-plugin-that-can-be-called-from-vimrc)
   - [What is a Vim plugin?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/619/what-is-a-vim-plugin)
   - [Add plugin directory](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/add-plugin-directory)
2. Remove [plugins](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) and perhaps even disallow it like [vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim). Is there a reason to have this tag? I don't see anyone being an expert on "plugins" in general (aside from plugin development, which we got covered with [plugin-system](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-system)), and in almost all cases the question aren't even *about* plugins as such, but *about* something else:

   - It's about a specific plugin, and should be tagged with this specific plugin (eg. [plugin-surround](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-surround)).
   - It's about accomplishing a specific task or solving a problem. These questions are better off being tagged about the problem (eg. [cursor-movement](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cursor-movement), [spell-checking](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spell-checking), etc.). More often than not, a plugin isn't even required.

Related meta posts:

- [Should there be a separate tag for each plugin?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/should-there-be-a-separate-tag-for-each-plugin)
- [Do we really need the [vim] tag?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/do-we-really-need-the-vim-tag)

Comment: I removed [tag:plugins] from a number of questions, and renamed the tag to [tag:plugin-system]. Blacklisting a tag is something only SE devs can do; we'll see if this tag returns (frequently) before I go bother someone for it.

Comment: On GDSE we have a [useless tags](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted) thread on meta to track and monitor tags we've soft-blacklisted. It's clunky though. If I were to do it again I'd probably use a tag (on meta) to track all the questions about tags that should be soft-blacklisted instead.

Answer (score 6):

I am in favor of renaming to [plugin-system](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-system) and blacklisting [plugins](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) itself.